# Why is clipping considered to be "too slow with cairo"?

Tags: user-interface, gtk, gtk3, gnome, cairo

I picked up working on [updating](https://github.com/codespunk/clearlooks-f14) the classic GNOME Clearlooks theme ([originally GTK2](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1080192/)), featured prominently in Fedora 14, for GTK3 by forking the outdated [Clearlooks-Phenix](https://github.com/jpfleury/clearlooks-phenix) project.

I've never worked on any GTK3 theme before so I came in with some false assumptions, namely that clipping rules for the CSS stylesheets would be be consistent with how a browser handles them.

One of these assumptions led me to file a [bug report](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/issues/2075) which was closed with the response:

> Yes, clipping is not being done in gtk3. It's too slow with cairo.

2D clipping has been a staple of accelerated graphics since the days of Windows 3.1. Cairo can already [take advantage of display hardware acceleration when available](https://www.cairographics.org/), with many of its [demos](https://www.cairographics.org/examples/) prominently using this feature.

Clipping to me seems like it should be so fundamentally basic on today's modern hardware that it should be effectively free. In what situations could it be considered slow enough to disable it selectively or entirely (some regions of GTK elements are seemingly clipped or overdrawn, I don't know which)? Is this something fundamental to Cairo, as it was mentioned specifically.

Comment: With `cairo_set_antialias(cr, CAIRO_ANTIALIAS_NONE)`, clipping becomes much faster. Maybe not useful to you, but useful to others viewing the question.

Answer (score 0):

Just as Timm Bäder wrote: Clipping with something that cuts pixels in half is complicated. (For example: A circle is more complicated than a rectangle that fits to the pixel grid.)

Sure, clipping so that only whole pixels are painted to can speed things up since less pixels need to be touched. However, a clip path that contains only 20% of a pixel means that some interpolation with the current value of the pixel is required.

Simple example: Paint a pixel white. `pixel = white` when the pixel is just set to white. But when only 20% of the pixel is to be drawn, you end up with something like `pixel = white * 0.2 + pixel * 0.8`, which is much more complicated.